# Change temperature F to C is having issues

Tags: c, function, int, double

I'm just started learning C programming. So I have problem with change temperature via Functions. Please check this program and where did I do mistake? Thank you!!!

```
 #include<stdio.h>
double f_to_c(double f);
double get_integer(void);

int main(void)
{
    double a;
    a = get_integer();

    printf("he degree in C:%f", f_to_c(a));

    return 0;
}
double get_integer(void)
{
    double n;
    printf("Enter the variable:");
    scanf_s("%f", &n);
        return n;
}
double f_to_c(double f)
{
    int f, c;
    c = 5.0 / 0.9*(f - 32.0);
    return c;
}
`
```

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: how come `get_integer()` returns a `double`?

Comment: also why are f and c declared as int in f_to_c ?

Comment: I tried to make program. But I couldn't build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
double f_to_c(double f);
double get_integer(void);

int main(void)
{
    double a;
    a = get_integer();

    printf("he degree in C:%lf\n", f_to_c(a));

    return 0;
}
double get_integer(void)
{
    double n;
    printf("Enter the variable:");
    scanf("%lf", &n);
        return n;
}
double f_to_c(double f)
{
    double c;
    c = 5.0/9*(f-32);
    return c;
}
```

As you can see:

1. Type of `c` variable in `f_to_c` is changed to double, because of you need a double return for that function
2. **Formula to convert F to C was not correct.**
3. Format specifier of your printf and scanf was not correct.

Answer (score 2):

In your case,

```
double f_to_c(double f)
{
    int f, c;
    c = 5.0 / 0.9*(f - 32.0);
    return c;
}
```

`int f` is shadowing the `double f`. Use some other name for the variable(s).

Essentially, you're trying to make use of an uninitialized automatic local variable which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 0):

in get_integer function return type is double, instead it should be integer

```
int get_integer(void)
{
int n;
printf("Enter the variable:");
scanf_s("%d", &n);
    return n;
}
```

in your other function f_to_c, return type is double but you're returning an integer

```
double f_to_c(double f)
{
int f;
double c;
c = (5.0 / 0.9)*(f - 32.0);
return c;
}
```

also at the start, you need to change your code to:

```
int main(void)
{
int a;
a = get_integer();

printf("he degree in C:%f", f_to_c(a));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I rolled back the last edit because ti removed one source of error in `f_to_c`. That function is still broken.

Comment: I did everything. But the result is very dangerous.

Comment: What's the result you're getting?

Comment: I entered the number 32 and got trash number 615164568.8888888

Comment: formulae which you used was incorrect: use the following one : (5.0 / 0.9)*(f - 32.0);   (edited in the post), also mention that a is of type integer and not double

Comment: Can I enter the variable without using get_integer??